# Why my forwarding didn't pass to the servlet class?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, forward

I develop a site with java ee ,Tomcat 9. IDE Eclipse I have a form in a login page ,which is submited to the LoginServlet for traitments and after traitments,  forward to the home page.
But with a debug and the results I saw that I never pass to the HomeServlet.

I already try to change the path, to change the action to the form

Here the web.xml

```
<!-- Servlet CONNEXION -->
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>ConnexionServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>servlets.ConnexionServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ConnexionServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/connexion</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 
<!-- Servlet ACCUEIL -->
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>AccueilServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>servlets.AccueilServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>AccueilServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/accueil</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The action of the connexion.jsp

It go to the ConnexionServlet for the traitments and forward to the home page

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final String VUE ="/WEB-INF/connexion.jsp";
private static final String VUE_ACCUEIL="/WEB-INF/accueil.jsp";

//Premier affichage de la page
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

    ConnexionTraitement conT = new ConnexionTraitement();
     boolean go=false;
    try {
        go = conT.connexionCliente(request);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(go) {
        /*System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
         String newRequest = request.getRequestURI() ;
         System.out.println( "servlet path"+request.getServletPath());
         newRequest = "/doyourhair/accueil";
         System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());*/


   this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE_ACCUEIL).forward(request, response);
    }else {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

It suppose to go to the home server (I have treatment like load a list from the database,so it is dynamic) and after show the page

But when Im submit, it go to the connexion servlet etc and forword just the simple home page without my list

Comment: This is one me , I make the treatment ( in the home page) in doGet instead of doPost()

Comment: What List? You are not setting any list.